# Cron not executing my system() statement in PERL

Tags: perl, shell, centos, cron

I am working on a PERL script that adds users from a database and then deletes the database. The code works fine when I execute it.

```
use DBI;
use strict;
my $database = "database";
my $hostname = "123.4.56.78";
my $port = "3306";
my $user = "user";
my $password = "password";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password) or die "Can't connect to database: ", $DBI::errstr, "\n";


my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM somewhere';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
system("useradd -g mygroup -d /home/somewhere/$row[0] -s /sbin/nologin $row[0]");
system("echo $row[0]:$row[1] | chpasswd");
}
my $sql_delete = 'TRUNCATE somewhere';
my $delete = $dbh->prepare($sql_delete);
$delete->execute();
```

However when I execute it through the Crontab, the system() statements are never executed, and the user are not added. They are deleted from the databse itself though.

```
* * * * * perl /var/perl/myperl.pl
```

The log says every minute:

```
Jul 26 15:42:01 ex40 CROND[7028]: (root) CMD (perl /var/perl/myperl.pl)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the full path to `useradd`. Crontab does not get a copy of the environment.

Comment: What error did `system` return? What output did `useradd` send to STDERR?

Comment: add first line #!/usr/bin/perl; change in the cron as  * * * * * /usr/bin/perl /var/perl/myperl.pl

Comment: @stevieb It worked thanks. You might want to write is as a proper answer.

Comment: I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the full path to `useradd` in the `system()` call.

Crontab does not get a copy of the environment, therefore the `PATH` environment variable isn't set.